# Selenium IDE 3.4.4 for Chrome, can't find the syntax to run Javascript scripts

Tags: selenium-ide

I've been looking around.
storeEval does not exist anymore.

Commands 'runScript' & 'executeScript' seem to replace it.

However, the syntax proposed in many posts javascript{script here} is not accepted: it refuses the first {. Same for the variables with the storeVars['foo'] which seems to be replaced by ${foo}.

Trying any javascript expression (even very simple) with both commands gets me a message 'Failed: missing ) after argument list'.

For instance: | run Script | "aString" + ${previouslyStoredVar} | outputVar |
(note: the syntax of the command seems to be 'runScript', but appears as 'run script' in the IDE window).

I tried adding a return(expression), putting brackets around the expression, enclosing ${previouslyStoredVar} in double quotes, trying with an even simpler expression, and everything I could think of, but with always the same error message.

What is it I am doing wrong? It must be obvious but I can't figure it out!

Many thanks,
E.

> My bad: just tried with 'return ${price_string}.substr(0, 5)' and it works. Have to find out why the other commands were not working. I'll dig and report!
>
> > OK, the pb remain but is quite different from my exepectation. The exact same expression and the same context works in a second test, but fails in the first test (with the missing parenthesis message). Seems to be a bug in the IDE then, or a corruption of some sort of the Selenium script...

Comment: fwiw, I find katalon and kantu are more reliable [selenium ide](https://a9t9.com/blog/selenium-ide-2018/)s, and both have useful extra features.

Comment: Many thanks! I should definitely explore them then! E.